Searching for phrases within files and leaving fingerprints
I searched for my name within files themselves on windows at work. I’ve now been accused of accessing 6,000 files (often at a speed of 6 per second) when actually I am convinced it was just the fact I searched for my name in the content of the file itself.
Can anyone confirm that searching for phrases within a file will create a process which shows you accessed the file?

Searching the content of the file requires reading the file, so you accessed the file. If the files are on a network location, then the IT staff may notice this and suspect a mass-download. You should explain to them what you did.

This is a personal issue, not really a technical issue. The solution to your immediate problem is to tell people what you were doing and why. The solution to your broader problem is probably to stop searching through all the org files for your name.

That’s all really helpful. Not sure of their motives but I have a duty to explain. Sadly the IT department has been little help so I’ve been looking for phrases i can use to better explain. Someone mention the data download from the storage array would be far smaller than total file size showing they weren’t downloaded too

The search tool is a process which accesses a file. That search tool will be working under your user profile so yes, there will be accesses to files that are linked to your account. Many organisations have programs that watch for suspicious access patterns and in the modern days of malware attacks and ransomware suddenly making a lot of small accesses to lots of files (or some sensitive files) could warrant investigation. Your actions may have been innocent, but you need to tell them the real reason for what you did so they know if your machine is compromised or has other issues.

Op, are the files you searched in OneDrive/Sharepoint or in a windows network share?

Yes, searching a file's contents is accessing the file.
There are many different ways to report on this kind of thing, but here's an example to confirm your question: The file access auditing built into windows can be configured to generate events like the screenshot below with your username, the file, and what access you used:

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-10/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4663
